# Batch for /f command why does my program not work?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

For some reason, none of the statements under the first for statement will run. I tried to enter a pause command directly under the for statement and it did not pause.

```
@echo off

net use Z: X

Z:

for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do (

    set doit=1

    for /f %%x in ('dir /b Z:\%%i') do if %%x == X set doit=0

    if %doit% == 1 echo %%i
)
```

I think the problem is in the first for statement since not even the pause command will run even when I put it directly under the for statement. But I tried typing the for statement in command prompt (without the extra % in %%i) and the statements underneath ran just fine. So is there a different syntax in batch files from cmd (other than %% instead of %)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably, "It still didn't work" doesn't provide any information useful in solving the problem. You should say what happened and what ou expected to happen as well as indication whether the target file existed and where.

I'd suggest a number of minor fixes:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
    set doit=1
    for /f %%x in ('dir /b Z:\%%i') do if /I "%%x"=="Fisher.png" set "doit="
    if DEFINED doit echo %%i
)
```

Your "pause failed" report may indicate that `Z:` contains no subdirectories as that `for /f` will list the subdirectories in basic format but if no subdirectories exist then it will not execute the main body. Hence, if you are looking for `Z:\Fisher.png` it will not be detected, otherwise you appear to be attempting to detect that file in any subdirectory under `Z:\`

Similarly, with your second `for`, you are matching filenames found against your target name. Quoting each side of the comparison-operator `==` ensures that if a filename which contains separators like <kbd>Space</kbd> is encountered, proper `if` syntax is maintained. The `/I` makes the comparison case-insensitive if required.

It's a standard response to use `delayededexpansion` and `!var!` but the method I've advocated means you can avoid `delayedexpansion`. The `if defined` syntax operates on the current stats of the target variables - either it is currently defined or not so if you `set` it to some value, then use `set "doit="` to cler the value, `if defined doit` works on whether or not the flag variable `doit` has been cleared by the inner `for` loop.

Why you use this complex mathod rather than

```
if exist "z:\%%i\Fisher.png" echo %%i
```

is a mystery. No doubt you have your reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
@echo off

net use Z: \\BRMH-FS01\StuHome$

Z:
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do (

    set doit=1

    for /f %%x in ('dir /b Z:\%%i') do if %%x == Fisher.png set doit=0

    if !doit! == 1 echo %%i
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand your code, all the manipulation with `%doit%` or `!doit!` ([npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) is right with [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)) and inner `for /f` loop seems to be rather redundant.

```
@echo off
net use Z: \\BRMH-FS01\StuHome$
Z:

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do If not exist "Z:\%%~i\Fisher.png" echo %%i
```

However, if one would do more actions conditionally, in next code snippet I keep `set "doit=0"` in `else` branch of `if` statement as any code block enclosed in `()` parentheses should not stay empty...

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do (

    If not exist "Z:\%%~i\Fisher.png" (
        set "doit=1"
        echo %%i
    ) else (
        set "doit=0"
    )
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~i` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)